# Dynamic radio buttons are not checked if different object have a same value

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux, radio-button

I need your help to fix displaying radio buttons checked based on the user's notification status.

The problem I currently have is when I pass down `isNotification` and if the different key (a different slug of object} shares the same value of it, the `checked` don't get displayed on UI.
I want to know why this wierd thing is happening, and what I am missing to display correctly.

Here are related codes and screenshots:
Notifications.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import NotificationForm from './NotificationForm';

class Notifications extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
// get notificationData object from backend
    this.props.notificationData.map((section) => this.props.fetchIsNotification(section.slug));
  }

  render() {
    // render empty tags until all API call finishes
    if (this.props.notificationData.some((data) => data.isNotification === undefined)) {
      return <div />;
    }
    return (
      <section>
        <form
          action={`/settings/notifications`}
          acceptCharset="UTF-8"
          method="post"
        >
          <input type="hidden" />
          {this.props.notificationData.map((section) => {
            return (
              <NotificationForm
                key={section.slug}
                slug={section.slug}
                text={section.caption}
                isNotification={section.isNotification}
                dispatch={this.props.updateIsNotification}
              />
            );
          })}

          <button type="submit">
            Update notification
          </button>
        </form>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default Notifications;
```

NotificationForm.js:

```
import React from 'react';

const NotificationForm = ({ text, slug, isNotification, handleUpdate }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <div htmlFor={1}>
        <label>
          <input
            id={1}
            type="radio"
            name="true"
            value="true"
            checked={isNotification === true}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_IS_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED',
                payload: e.currentTarget.value,
                slug,
              })
            }
          />
          Notify me
        </label>
        <label htmlFor={2}>
          <input
            id={2}
            type="radio"
            name="false"
            value="false"
            checked={isNotification === false}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_IS_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED',
                payload: e.currentTarget.value,
                slug,
              })
            }
          />
          Do not notify me.
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NotificationForm;
```

this.props.notificationData example data of reducer initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  notificationData: [
    {
      slug: 'receive_dm',
      caption: 'Whe you received DM',
      isNotification: false,
    },
    {
      slug: 'like_comment',
      caption: 'When you got like',
      isNotification: false,
    },
    {
      slug: 'comment_post',
      caption: 'When you got comment',
      isNotification: false,
    },
    {
      slug: 'community_post',
      caption: 'When someone posted on your community',
      isNotification: true,
    }
  ]
};
```

As you see in the screenshot, since object with slug of `receive_dm`, `link_comment` and `comment_post` have the same value, `isNotification: false`, the radio buttons aren't checked. And the `community_post` row get checked because `isNotification: true` and it doesn't share the same value with other rows's `isNotification`.

[image]

However I see `checked` property in input tag on dev tool for `receive_dm`, `link_comment` and `comment_post` 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

radio buttons are grouped by name attribute of input tags. In your code, you wrote name="true" or name="false" for input tags. Those are wrong. so all of input tags who has name="true" are in one group and same as for the name="false".

Please try the below code.

```
import React from 'react';

const NotificationForm = ({ text, slug, isNotification, handleUpdate }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <div htmlFor={1}>
        <label>
          <input
            id={1}
            type="radio"
            name={slug} // it must be uniqe for groups and same in one group
            value="true"
            checked={isNotification === true}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_IS_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED',
                payload: e.currentTarget.value,
                slug,
              })
            }
          />
          Notify me
        </label>
        <label htmlFor={2}>
          <input
            id={2}
            type="radio"
            name={slug} // it must be uniqe for groups and same in one group
            value="false"
            checked={isNotification === false}
            onChange={(e) =>
              dispatch({
                type: 'FETCH_IS_NOTIFICATION_FULFILLED',
                payload: e.currentTarget.value,
                slug,
              })
            }
          />
          Do not notify me.
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default NotificationForm;
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked properly.  This answer proved me that I didn't understand what are input tag's name attribute is for!

Comment: Then please vote my answer, haha, if you are satisfied with my answer.